The recursion Theorem: Bottom-up vs top-down proof
The Recursion Theorem (for $\mathbb{N}$) states that for any set $A$, any $a\in A$, and any function $g:\mathbb{N}\times A\to A$, there exists a unique function $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ such that

$f(0)=a$, and
$f(n+1)=g(n,f(n))$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

In Hrbacek & Jech's Introduction to Set Theory, the authors construct $f$ from the bottom-up as follows (p.48):
Define the familly
$$F=\{t\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times A)\,\,|\,\,\text{for some $\,m\in\mathbb{N}$, }t:(m+1)\to A,\,\text{with $\,t(0)=a\,$ and $\,t_{k+1}=g(k,t(k))\,$ for $\,0\leq k<m$}\},$$
and set
$$f=\bigcup F.$$
The bottom-up idea is intuitively clear, and quite neat: They make $f$ up of compatible finite-domain functions defined using the instructions provided by the function $g$.
On the other hand, in Halmos' Naive Set Theory the author proves a version of the Recursion Theorem using a top-down approach (p.48 as well. Quite the coincidence!). Halmos' proof can be easily modified to suit the version of the Recursion Theorem I have stated here.
Define the family
$$F'=\{S\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times A)\,\,|\,\,\text{$(0,a)\in S\,$ and $\,\forall x\,\forall n\,[(n,x)\in S\implies(n+1,g(n,x))\in S]$}\},$$
and set
$$f=\bigcap F',$$
which we can do because $F'\neq\emptyset$ since $\mathbb{N}\times A\in F'$.
The intuitive idea is also clear here, as conditions 1. and 2. of the Recursion Theorem are built up into the definition of $F'$. That is, put in the family every subset of $\mathbb{N}\times A$ containing all the ordered pairs verifying conditions 1. and 2. and take the intersection of that family in order to get rid of the chaff. Quite neat as well
My personal position on it is simple: learn both! I can see why both perspectives are good. But is there a tendency to prefer a method over the other? Both generalize into the transfinite realm, as each of the books illustrate in later chapters.
Do both approaches generalize to recursion over well-founded sets? Could you please provide a reference?

One quick observation: the first also works with minor adaptations for certain "functions" defined on a proper class, such as the ordinal rank of a set (in ZFC), or ordinal arithmetic, whereas the second approach wouldn't work at least in ZFC.

For instance, in the example of ordinal arithmetic to define the function $\alpha + \cdot$, there is no set such that $(0, \alpha) \in S$, $(\beta, \sigma) \in S \Rightarrow (\beta \cup { \beta }, \sigma \cup { \sigma }) \in S$ and $[\forall i \in I, (\beta_i, \sigma_i) \in S] \Rightarrow (\bigcup_{i\in I} \beta_i, \bigcup_{i\in I} \sigma_i) \in S$.  If there were, then you could use the axiom of replacement to extract a set containing all ordinals, which would lead to a contradiction via the Burali-Forti paradox.

@DanielSchepler On p.70 of Halmos' Naive Set Theory, he states (a version) of the Transfinite Recursion Theorem. The proof proceeds using a top-down approach taking the intersection of a suitable family. Here's theorem, for your convenience: If $W$ is a well-ordered set, and if $f$ is a sequence function of type $W$ in a set $X$, then there exists a unique function $U$ from $W$ into $X$ such that $U(a) = f(U^{a})$ for each $a$ in $W$.

The reason the top down approach fails in Daniel Schepler's example is because the ordinals do not form a set. Halmos's approach works because $W$ is a set, and so is $W\times X$, and you can do everything needed. But you cannot form a set of all ordinals. For that reason, there is no function in the normal sense that can be defined on them. However, there are relations that act like functions, and a recursive definition similar to your recursive theorem can be used to define them.

@PaulSinclair Thanks, yes, I understood Daniel Schelper's example quite well, which is why I added the statement of Halmos' transfinite version of the theorem. $W$ is a set.  All is well. As for your last sentence: could you make that more precise? Or perhaps you know where I may find the version of the theorem for proper classes?

How you handle it for proper classes is going to depend on which set theory you choose. ZFC has no concept of classes, so involves relations, not classes, and the theorem will be not in ZFC itself, but a metamathematical theorem about ZFC. Other set theories provide different frameworks for what could be called classes. Von Neumann offers classes as objects that cannot contained in another collection. Russell & Whitehead build an entire hierarchy of classes. Grothendieck essentially creates a second level of ZFC for proper classes (this is my description, not his).

As for where you can read up on it, sorry, but these are just things I picked up from various places over the years, I am not a good source for references.

On p.40 of Azriel Levy's Basic Set Theory, the author states and proves (via the bottom-up approach) a version of the Recursion Theorem for classes. What he considers a class appears to be (according to the author himself, p.11) only minor different from von Neuman's notion of class. The statement of the theorem: Let $\langle A,R\rangle$ be a well-ordered class. Given a set term $\tau$, there exists a unique function $F$ on $A$ such that for every $x\in A$, $F(x)=\tau(F\upharpoonleft A)$, where $\tau$ may also have parameters which are class- or set-variables.
